# MySQL Running Total Based On a Column Values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to produce a table with running totals based on a column

Let's say I have a table like this:

| company | year | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| google | 2020 | 16 |
| google | 2021 | 18 |
| apple | 2020 | 20 |
| apple | 2021 | 26 |
| bp | 2020 | 15 |
| bp | 2021 | 10 |

desired result is

| company | year | profit | cum profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | 2019 | 16 | 16 |
| google | 2020 | 18 | 34 |
| google | 2021 | 13 | 47 |
| apple | 2019 | 20 | 20 |
| apple | 2020 | 26 | 46 |
| apple | 2021 | 21 | 67 |
| bp | 2019 | 15 | 15 |
| bp | 2020 | 10 | 25 |
| bp | 2021 | 17 | 42 |

I find a way but it adds up continuously without looking for company names. Every company should have its own running total.

This is my way:

```
SELECT company, year, profit, 
CAST((@cum_profit:= @cum_profit + profit) AS DECIMAL(16, 2)) AS cum_profit
FROM table  
GROUP BY company, year) AS t
JOIN(SELECT @cum_profit:= 0) AS tmp;
```

Result is continuous running total but I need every company's own running total.

Answer (score 1):

For older version of MySQL you can do it with subquery and in MySQL 8.0 and above you can use `sum()over()` window function partitioned by company column.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table company_profit(company varchar(50), year int, profit int );
 insert into company_profit values('google',    2019,   16);    
 insert into company_profit values('google',    2020,   18);    
 insert into company_profit values('google',    2021,   13);    
 insert into company_profit values('apple', 2019,   20);    
 insert into company_profit values('apple', 2020,   26);    
 insert into company_profit values('apple', 2021,   21);    
 insert into company_profit values('bp',    2019,   15);    
 insert into company_profit values('bp',    2020,   10);    
 insert into company_profit values('bp',    2021,   17);
```

Running total query with subquery (for older version than MySQL 8.0)

```
 select company,year,profit,
 (select sum(profit) from company_profit c where c.company=cp.company and c.year<=cp.year) as cum_profit
 from company_profit cp
```

Output:

| company | year | profit | cum_profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| google | 2019 | 16 | 16 |
| google | 2020 | 18 | 34 |
| google | 2021 | 13 | 47 |
| apple | 2019 | 20 | 20 |
| apple | 2020 | 26 | 46 |
| apple | 2021 | 21 | 67 |
| bp | 2019 | 15 | 15 |
| bp | 2020 | 10 | 25 |
| bp | 2021 | 17 | 42 |

Running total query with window function (for MySQL 8.0 and higher):

```
 select company,year,profit,sum(profit)over( partition by company order by company,year) as cum_profit
 from company_profit
```

Output:

| company | year | profit | cum_profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2019 | 20 | 20 |
| apple | 2020 | 26 | 46 |
| apple | 2021 | 21 | 67 |
| bp | 2019 | 15 | 15 |
| bp | 2020 | 10 | 25 |
| bp | 2021 | 17 | 42 |
| google | 2019 | 16 | 16 |
| google | 2020 | 18 | 34 |
| google | 2021 | 13 | 47 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1f75735329334218b63cec9483ed3907)*

Comment: @CihanAltun thanks for sharing data. I have added new answers. Please have a look.

Comment: This is not the solution, this is simple group by. Check out my desired result table please

Comment: @CihanAltun sorry I misunderstood your problem. I have revised my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a running total.  It looks like simple aggregation:

```
select company, field, sum(profit)
from t
group by company, field;
```

Comment: Hi, I edited the question, can you review it?